# How to delete relation data in many to many using Typeorm?

Tags: express, typeorm

What I want to do is when I delete Category I wanted to automatically also delete related Todo.  They have a many to many relationship

### Category Entity

```js
@Entity('categories')
export class Category extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryColumn({type: 'bigint'})
    id:string;

    @Column()
    name:string;

    @ManyToMany(
        ()=>TodoItem, 
        todoItem => todoItem.categories
        ,{onDelete:"CASCADE"}
    ) 
    @JoinTable({
        name:"categories_todos",
        joinColumn:{
            name:"categories", 
            referencedColumnName:"id"
        },
        inverseJoinColumn:{
            name:"todos",
            referencedColumnName:"id"
        }
    })    
    todos:TodoItem[]

    @ManyToOne(
        ()=>User,
        user=>user.categoires
    )
    @JoinColumn({
        name: 'user_id'
    })
    user:User
}
```

### Todo Entity

```js
@Entity('todoItem')
export class TodoItem extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id:string;
    @Column()
    completed:boolean;
    
    @Column()
    title: string; 


    @ManyToMany(
        ()=>Category,
        category => category.todos
    )
    categories:Category[]

   

}
```

and Here's my delete category API

```js
router.delete('/api/category/:categoryId',async(req:express.Request,res:express.Response)=>{
    const { categoryId } = req.params
    const category = await Category.findOne(categoryId)
    if(!category){
        return res.status(404).json({msg:"category not found"})
    }
    await Category.delete(category)
    return res.status(200).json(category) 
});
```

I tried **cascade:true** and **onDelete:"CASCADE"** , but it won't work , I wonder what is the problem, below is  my entity and delete API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a `category` will not delete any `todoItem` entity it contains. Instead, `cascade` will only remove the relations from the `category_todos_todoItem` table (automatically created by TypeORM).

To delete each `todoItem` in the `category`, loop through `category.todos` and delete each `todoItem` manually:

```
category.todos.forEach( async (todoItem) => await TodoItem.delete(todoItem.id) );
```

You can also try doing this automatically with a [Subscriber Class](https://typeorm.io/listeners-and-subscribers#what-is-a-subscriber)

NOTE: You will encounter errors if you have foreign keys constraining the relation. In that case, use a [query](https://typeorm.io/data-source-api#query) to delete all occurrences of that `todoItem` from `category_todos_todoItem`. Then you can delete the the `todoItem`.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` method is plain and won't do the trick:

```
/**
 * Deletes entities by a given criteria.
 * Unlike save method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included.
 * Executes fast and efficient DELETE query.
 * Does not check if entity exist in the database.
 */
```

You could try with `remove`

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but this is what worked for me

```
const instance = await this.categoryRepository.findOneBy({ id });
Object.assign(instance, { todos: [] });
await this.categoryRepository.save(instance);
return await this.categoryRepository.delete(id);
```